# Копирование через spread-оператор с заменой поля второго уровня

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Всем привет, передо мной стоит задача, которую хочу решить за минимальное число символов, подробнее в коде ниже:

```js
// пусть есть объект
const DATA = {
    name: 'vlad',
    surname: 'Kudashov',
    passport: {
        serial: '4518',
        number: '124202',
        issue: '24022017'
    }
}

// Копирование с заменой полей верхнего уровня
const DATA_changeFirstLevel = {...DATA, surname: 'KudashEv'};

// А вот если хочу копировать с заменой второго уровня
const DATA_changeSecondLevel = {...DATA, {...DATA.passport, serial: '4444'}}

// но так нельзя(((

// можно же вот так, но так не коротко
const DATA_changeCorrectSecondLevel = {...DATA, passport: Object.assign(DATA.passport, {serial: '4444'})}
```

Хотелось бы найти короткое решение и, возможно, объяснение почему невозможен nested spread оператор

Comment: Тут вариант с глубокой вложенностью. Так просто не получится. Либо рекурсивную функцию писать, либо JSON.stringify, а затем JSON.parse. Это паршивый по производительности вариант, но если он выполняется на клиенте, то когда мы о клиентах думали? ))) (шутка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const DATA = {
    name: 'vlad',
    surname: 'Kudashov',
    passport: {
        serial: '4518',
        number: '124202',
        issue: '24022017'
    }
}

const DATA_changeSecondLevel = {...DATA, passport: {...DATA.passport, serial: '4444'}}

console.log(DATA_changeSecondLevel);
```

Comment: А если уровней вложенности будет не 1, а 300?

Comment: @AlexSazonov если будет, то это уже другая задача, а тут написано `А вот если хочу копировать с заменой ВТОРОГО уровня`

Comment: ой, да, спасибо, что -то я не подумал